# Appropirate VS2013 Project Template for AngularJS and Web API 2 Application

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-web-api2

This question might be ridiculous. Sorry for that.

I have worked with ASP.NET MVC application. Now I would like to start with AngularJS and ASP.Net Web API 2 in my next web application.

In my previous MVC projects, I selected **Empty** with the **MVC** checkbox checked.

What project template should i choose to start with?

Thank you.

Comment: Do you plan to use `.cshtml` at all ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select

```
New project/Web/Asp.NET web application
```

Then select WEB API (you can change authentication from here)

Your project is created.
Now open nugget packages manager and update to "Microsoft ASP.NET Web API x.x" (currently 2.2).

Answer (score 1):

There is the [AngularJS SPA Template](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/5af151b2-9ed2-4809-bfe8-27566bfe7d83) available in `MSDN`.

It has already 18K downloads, used by many, and constantly updated (last update from two weeks ago).

To add WebAPI 2.0, just right-click on the project > Manage NuGet Packages > Find and reference *Microsoft ASP.NET Web API 2.1 Web Host*

Then activate it in Startup.cs

Comment: Seems like an appropriate template would not use any of the MVC template pages for authentication, but instead use angular with http-auth-interceptor and Web API 2 with Token authentication.